# How to integrate AD groups into linux?

Tags: active-directory, redhat

I know there are a lot of these questions, but here's another one.

I need to make AD users have access to linux groups and access to application users without having to manually place them.

I need to do this so that, for example, a person from the 'JAVA' AD group can only work on java directories and filesystems in linux, as well as perform application access.

What I have already done:

- Integrate AD into Linux and allow them to access it.
- New users appear in linux (/ home) with properties "Join user domain"

How do I make them automatically appear within a specific group?

Answer (score 1):

Configure NSS to reference the directory for users and groups, such as with sssd. Groups do not have to be in /etc/group, that is why the NSS abstraction exists.

Confirm the correct user subset are members of this group in the directory (AD DS in this case). Use `getent group` on the Linux box.

Use the "directory" group in file permissions and elsewhere, as you would a "local" group.